# How would i use bayes theorem for the following?

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

How would I use Bayes Theorem with this? Please write out the steps I need to take, really confused by it. Thanks!

A box has 2 blue and 2 green jelly beans. A bag has 9 blue and 4 green jelly beans. A jelly bean is selected at random from the box and placed in the bag. Then a jelly bean is selected at random from the bag. If a green jelly bean is selected from the bag, what is the probability that the transferred jelly bean was green?

Would I use the following formula?:
P(E)=P(F)P(E|F)+P(F^C)P(E|F^C)

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the *conditional* probability $P(TG|BG)$ with $TG$ being the event that the Transferred bean was Green, and $BG$ the event of picking a Green bean from the Bag after the transfer.

To calculate this, use Bayes' Law:

$$P(TG|BG)=\frac{P(BG|TG)\cdot P(TG)}{P(BG)}$$